# How to sort a data in desc order based on string column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a list of data in desc order from my database. But it isn't giving the result that I want.

- **table name:** `testing`
- **column name:** `id(pk), fiscal_no`

**My query is**: 
`` SELECT * FROM `testing` ORDER BY fiscal_no DESC ``

**For this query, I am getting this result**

[image]

But I want the result that should be desc by fiscal_no like this based on the `fiscal_no` last num

[image]

Is there any query available for this kind of result?

Answer (score 3):

SYN#JOB#*F*EB is actually before SYN#JOB#*J*AN in descending order.

You should consider the `SUBSTRING`function (or sometimes `SUBSTR`) to sort starting at the 13th character of fiscal_no column.

If you use MySQL, here is the [ref](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp). The sort statement should be:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(fiscal_no, 13) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM testing ORDER BY SUBSTRING(fiscal_no,13,3) DESC;
```

---

`SUBSTRING` Function Syntax:

```
SUBSTRING(string, start, length)
```

**But I suggest you'd better re-design your table schema, you table design don't match 1NF**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM testing ORDER BY substring(fiscal_no,13,3) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the integer value is the last 3 characters in all values in column fiscal_no, one workaround you can do is:

```
SELECT * FROM testing ORDER BY substring(fiscal_no,-3) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `reverse` or `cast` can do something in this

```
ORDER BY REVERSE(fiscal_no) DESC

OR 

ORDER BY CAST(fiscal_no AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `substring_index()`:

```
order by substring_index(fiscal_no, '#', -1) desc,
         fiscal_no desc
```

If you know that it is always the last three characters, then you can use `right()`:

```
order by right(fiscal_no, 3) desc,
         fiscal_no desc
```